# How to get the author and chapter names in header; alternatively using fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, book-design

I want to set a header/footer which shows:

1. Chapter name on odd numbered page;
2. Author name (different authors in different chapters) in even numbered pages;
3. Page number in central footer.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

**Updated:**
A MWE is given as

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage{blindtext}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\begin{document}

\chapter{Wombat}  
Author Aa, And Author Bb  
\blindtext[5]  
\section{tabmow}  
\blindtext[5]  

\chapter{Capybara}  
Author Cc, And Author Dd  
\blindtext[5]  
\section{arabypac}  
\blindtext[5]  

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you don't want the `\section` header to appear at all?

Comment: Yes, for now....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the documentation for ***fancyhdr*** package, I got the work done as below:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\newcommand{\TheAuthor}{} % As given in documentation of **fancyhdr**
\newcommand{\Author}[1]{\renewcommand{\TheAuthor}{#1}}
\fancyhead{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[CO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[CE]{\slshape \TheAuthor}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.6pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
\pagestyle{fancy} % Return the page headers back to the "fancy" style
\input{./Chap1/Chap1} % Include the chapters as separate files from the Chapters folder (first <Chap1> is folder and second one is file Chap1.tex)
\fancyhead{}
\end{document}
```

And my Chap1.tex is:

```
% Chapter 1  
\chapter{Introduction}  
\Author{PQR}  
\section{Introduction}  
\lipsum[1-22]  
\section{Background}  
\lipsum[1-22]  
\subsection{History}  
\lipsum[1-22]
```

Comment: So how is this different than my proposed solution?

Comment: In my solution, the command looks very easy to understand for novice users like me. It is much easier.

Comment: What makes it easier to understand? You're using `\documentclass` options that aren't needed, and include text via an external file. What I'm getting at is that you should consider upvoting contributions and/or accept answers as *the solution to your problem* (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)) rather than adding content that replicates other answers. What you think might be easier to understand is purely subjective, don't you think?

Comment: I guess I must thank you, first. Your solution that works,... absolutely! However, I am looking for simple solutions.

Comment: I assume what you consider non-simple (or difficult) is the use of `@` symbols in definitions and the use of [`\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764).

Comment: Yes, and I have updated my MWE... as you pointed out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

The following introduces `\chapterauthor` to set and store the authors associated with your `\chapter`s. This allows you to use the stored details within the `\fancyhead[LE]` part.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\chapterauthor}[1]{%
  \def\@chapterauthor{#1}% Store chapter authors
  {\bfseries #1}% Set chapter authors
  \par
}

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}% Chapter details in book
\fancyhead[LE]{\@chapterauthor}% Stored \chapterauthor details
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule (default)
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Wombat}
\chapterauthor{Author Aa, And Author Bb}
\blindtext[5]
\section{tabmow}
\blindtext[5]

\chapter{Capybara}
\chapterauthor{Author Cc, And Author Dd}
\blindtext[5]
\section{arabypac}
\blindtext[5]

\chapter*{Mara}
\chapterauthor{}% No chapter author
\blindtext[5]
\section{aram}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```